# "We did something with a friend" or "I did something with a friend"

Tags: grammar

If the activity involved only me and one other friend, e.g. playing tennis, I know "I played tennis with Jake" is correct. However, is it possible to also say something like "We played tennis with Jake"? If not, is there a slight adaptation in the structure which allows for the use of "We"?

Comment: No, you can't "incorporate" the extra person to justify switching your subject from singular ***I*** to plural ***we*** like that. The nearest equivalent I can think of is something like ***Jake and I,*** (or less formally, ***Me and Jake,***) ***...we played tennis together.*** In that phrasing, the element before the comma correctly establishes the plurality of the subject *before* it's actually used syntactically.

Comment: Your sentence looks like a literal translation from Russian. In Russian you say something like "We _**with**_ my friend" to mean "I and my friend".

Comment: You can put the parenthetical with a precising (identifying clearly) appositive after the pronoun: 'We – Jake and I – played each other at tennis.' 
FumbleFingers' example is a left dislocation (the 'we' adds nothing).

Comment: @fev, I seem to remember that Old Norse did this too, even using the dual "vit" (we two).

Comment: @ColinFine Very possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you and Jake played tennis then

> I played tennis with Jake

is correct.

Jake did not play tennis with Jake. Therefore there is only one person who played tennis with Jake, and it is you.

If you want to emphasise the "we" then

> We played tennis together.

is what you need.